# In Angular How do I populate a property from the html

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have created a component called Wizard which has two properties: Sections & Steps

here is an extract from the component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Section } from './models/section';
import { Step } from './models/step';

@
  Component({
    styleUrls: ['wizard.component.css'],
    selector: 'sym-wizard',
    templateUrl: './wizard.component.html'
  })
export class WizardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() sections: Section[];
  @Input() steps: Step[];

  currentStep: Step;
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

**How can I populate the properties from the HTML view so that the following will populate the Section and Steps Properties?**

```
<sym-wizard>
  <sections>
    <section name="name1"></section>
    <section name="name2"></section>
    <section name="name3"></section>
  </sections>

  <steps>
    <step name="step1" section="name1">
    </step>
    <step name="step2" section="name1"></step>
    <step name="step3" section="name2"></step>
    </steps>
</sym-wizard>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this inside your `WizardComponent`:

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/httpsstackoverflowcoma616122846433166?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```js
  @ContentChildren(StepComponent, { descendants: true }) 
  _steps: QueryList<StepComponent>;

  @ContentChildren(SectionComponent, { descendants: true })
  _sections: QueryList<StepComponent>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this._steps.toArray().length);
    console.log(this._sections.toArray().length);
  }
```

Comment: Hi I've edited the example to not have `[sections]="sections" [steps]="steps"`

Comment: I've updated my answer. I'll put together a stackblitz demo... it'll be easier to follow if I  didn't get it right yet.

Comment: Thanks @julianobrasil Ive not got this working yet on my example but looking at your Stackbliz it seems to be what I need to do

Answer (score 0):

You can check `@ContentChilren` decorator. [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren). If I understand you correctly this is what you need.
So, in your case it'll be like:

```js
@ContentChildren("section") sectionsQuery!: QueryList<SectionComponent>;
```

And then in `AfterViewInit` hook:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sections = this.sectionsQuery?.map(section => ({name: section.name}));
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-example0-wdorph)
I used divs in this example, but should work for everything else as well.